# uniform convergence of $\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)^n$

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

I want to find whether $f_n(x)=\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)^n$ on $[0,\infty)$ uniformly converges or not.

First after rearranging, I have
\begin{align}
\left(  \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)^n = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^n} 
\end{align}
First I know $1+\frac{1}{x^2} >1$ for $x \geq 0$, and in this case $f_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. **[Actually I have trouble with $x \rightarrow \infty$, in this case $1+\frac{1}{x^2} =1$ and so $f_n \rightarrow 1$]**

Now I am trying to show whether $f_n \rightrightarrows f=0$  To do that, I am trying to show $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n =0$ where
\begin{align}
T_n = \sup\{|f_n(x) - f(x)| | x\in D\}
\end{align}
From binomial expansion of $(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^n$, I have
\begin{align}
\left(  \frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)^n = \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{x^2})^n}  \leq \frac{1}{1+\frac{n}{x^2}} < 1
\end{align}
This seems $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} T_n \neq 0$...

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that $$
\mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \left| {\left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{{1 + x^2 }}} \right)^n  - 0} \right| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x > 0} \left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{{1 + x^2 }}} \right)^n  \ge \left( {\frac{{\sqrt n ^2 }}{{1 + \sqrt n ^2 }}} \right)^n  = \frac{1}{{\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n }} \ge \frac{1}{e}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sketch:** Pointwise, we see that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right)^n = 0.
\end{align}
Hence, if $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly then $f \equiv 0$, i.e. for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $n\ge N$, we have that
\begin{align}
|f_n(x)-f(x)| = |f_n(x)|<\varepsilon
\end{align}
for all $x \in [0, \infty)$. However, consider $x_n = n$, then we have that
\begin{align}
|f_n(n)|<\varepsilon
\end{align}
which is false (Why?).

Comment: $\sqrt{n}$ also works!. ..Since, $f_n(\sqrt{n})=\Big(\frac{n}{1+n}\Big)^n \to \frac{1}{e}$!

Comment: Oh I see, since $f_n(n) = \left(\frac{n^2}{1+n^2} \right)^n$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(n) = 1$, $|f_n(n)| < \epsilon$ is false